# When to do .repartition(Int AnyValue) in Spark, right after reading the Parquet (or) after running computations on that Parquet?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a parquet file that is partitioned based on a date column, what could be the optimized way to do .reparition()? Should I do it right after I read the parquet, like below:

```
 val myPq = "/hive/data/myPq.db/myPq"
    sparkSession.read
      .format("parquet")
      .load(inputConfig.getString("myPq")).repartition(200).createOrReplaceTempView("myPqView")
```

Or After performing a wide range of transformations like filter, map etc..

```
def readMyPq(){
val myPq = "/hive/data/myPq.db/myPq"
    sparkSession.read
      .format("parquet")
   .load(inputConfig.getString("myPq")).repartition(200).createOrReplaceTempView("myPqView")

val returnDF = spark.sql("Multiple Transformations from createOrReplaceTempView")
}
```

What could be a Good way? Thank you in Advance

Answer (score 4):

It completely depends on when you believe your data would be most unbalanced.  If the data is read in in an unbalanced way (e.g. 1 large partition, 199 small ones), you may want to repartition right away.

If the data is balanced when you read it in but after your filter/map/etc there's a large partition and a bunch of small ones, at this point you may want to repartition.

It may even make sense to repartition in both places if your data requires it.
Just remember that repartitioning isn't cheap and should be balanced against the cost of not repartitioning.  Benchmark with some sample of your normal data flow and see the result.

Answer (score 2):

I do not see a difference between your code snippets, other than the second being a method containing the first. However, repartition shuffles your data across executors. As such, if you have the option of repartitioning later in your code, **it is best to repartition on your smallest possible set of data**. If you are using filters as you specified and this filters out a large amount of data, it would probably be best to call repartition after this occurs.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, the second snippet has many transformations which I redacted.

Comment: @Pavan_Obj, could you give a brief description of the transformations so I can better assist? Even without code it could still be helpful. Something like "map each line to an array, then flatMap elements based on some attribute, then filter out empty elements". Even with this detail it would be easier to help out